# Why the C# code and HTML content mixed in MVC4 and termed as Razor Language ?

Tags: razor

Why the C# code and HTML content mixed in MVC4 and termed as Razor Language ? Is it not confusing still compared to ASPX pages?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question will be closed.

Comment: @mason: Thanks for responses guys.Appreciated. I am new bee in MVC, wanted to know why to use Razor when I am happy with ASPX. It made me feel clumsy to have my HTML code clubbed with C# code. Still MVC is said to highlight feature- "separation of concerns". Got confused how does this apply. I know other part Controllers,M and V are separated.

Comment: It's not about separating different languages from each other. It's about separating concerns. So things that are purely GUI related should be on the HTML code, things that are related to the Model should be only with the other model code etc. I personally use ASPX and Web Forms, but the same thing holds true.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find Razor code to be less confusing than C# in ASPX.

It just seems more fluent and easier to read.

Here's a quick read on some of the main syntax used in Razor:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Comment: Kehrk: It's really valuable article on Razor. Thanks.

Comment: MVC is really a powerful framework to work with. I recommend doing some reading on it and maybe even building some practice projects just to get a feel for it. You can do a lot with MVC and I've loved it ever since I started using it mid-last year.